# How is stSearch triggered?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I would like to know how stSearch is triggered or how could i trigger it by myself.

My problem is i have an array of object all having a creationDate.

I would like to be able to filter the array from a creation date to the other.

To do that I use a datepicker from ui-bootstrap like this :

```
<input uib-datepicker-popup="DD/MM/YYYY" st-search="'fromDate'">
<input uib-datepicker-popup="DD/MM/YYYY" st-search="'toDate'">
```

I also have a custom filter that is triggered on stSearch that i placed onto the table like this :

```
<table st-set-filter="myCustomFilter" st-table="myDatas">
```

When I change the date on a datepicker the stSearch is not triggered for some reason.

I don't know if someone faced the same problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the source code for the st-search directive: https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stSearch.js

The relevant portions of the code are:

```
var promise = null;
var event = attr.stInputEvent || stConfig.search.inputEvent;

// attr.$observe and scope.$watch calls...

// view -> table state
element.bind(event, function (evt) {
  evt = evt.originalEvent || evt;
  if (promise !== null) {
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
  }

  promise = $timeout(function () {
    tableCtrl.search(evt.target.value, attr.stSearch || '');
    promise = null;
  }, throttle);
});
```

From the above, the search (`tableCtrl.search`) is triggered when the event, which defaults to the input event, fires on the input element that `st-search` is applied to. You can change the event that triggers the call to `tableCtrl.search` through the `st-input-event` directive, e.g. `<input st-input-event="change" st-search="'fromDate'" ...>`. Hopefully that gives you a starting point for identifying the source of your problem.